# KnockoutJS accordion like behaviour with custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to build some accordion like functionality with KnockoutJS and custom bindings

So far I've got it half way there:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div class="item"> <span data-bind="text: name() ? name() : 'New Thing'"></span>

        <br /> <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.toggleVisibility">Show / Hide</a>

        <div class="fullDetails" data-bind="accordion: visible">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: addItem">Add new item</a>
```

and my Javascript

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray([new ItemModel()]);

    self.addItem = function (item) {

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function (i) {
            i.visible(false);
        });
        self.items.push(new ItemModel())

    };

    self.toggleVisibility = function (item) {

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function (i) {
            i.visible(false);
        });

        item.visible(!item.visible())
    };
};

var ItemModel = function () {
    this.visible = ko.observable(true);
    this.name = ko.observable();
}

ko.bindingHandlers.accordion = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();

        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value) ? $(element).slideDown() : $(element).slideUp();
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Also on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/PPAsK/

Some issues I am having:

**Show/Hide link**
This seems to scroll up and then immediately scroll down again.

**Adding a new item**
I was trying to get the item currently visible to `slideUp`, then the new item to `slideDown` but this isn't working - whatever item is visible slidesUp, but the new item just appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Issue 1:

you are always showing on show/hide link click because the item previously gets reset to visible(false). Fix:

```
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items(), function (i) {

        //don't bother with the item, we take care of it later
        if (item !== i) {
            i.visible(false);
        }

    });
```

- Issue 2:

you need to start with the added item hidden, then apply self.toggleVisibility(newItem)
This will take care of hiding the others and animating the new one

```
self.addItem = function (item) {
        var newItem = new ItemModel();

        //make sure it starts hidden
        newItem.visible(false);
        self.items.push(newItem);

        //highlight it the usual way
        self.toggleVisibility(newItem);
    };
```

fixed version here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tudorilisoi/3LzbT/8/

Comment: Almost there... the new item still just appears... I was trying to get it to slide up whatever one is visible (this bit is working) then slide down the new one... Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Issue #2: the effect is seamless because both the old dissapearing and the new one appearing animate at the same time. You can make it more obvious by hiding the current item (if any), then showing the new item with a delay, using window.setTimeout